# JUnit test failing with NPE when testing validator method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am working through the below tutorial:

http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html

I am trying to test the validate method in the class below:

```
public class PriceIncreaseValidator implements Validator {
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        PriceIncrease pi = (PriceIncrease) obj;
        if (pi == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("percentage", "error.not-specified", null, "Value required.");
        }
........
}
```

Below is my JUnit test case:

```
private PriceIncreaseValidator priceIncreaseValidator;
private PriceIncrease priceIncrease;
private Errors errors;

public void testEmptyPriceIncrease() {

    priceIncreaseValidator.validate(priceIncrease, errors); // This is where I get NPE

    assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
}
```

So I get the NPE when invoking the validate method in my JUnit test case.
The test and class all compiles fine.

I have tried converting priceIncrease into an object as per below, but still no luck:

```
Object obj = priceIncrease;
//validate
priceIncreaseValidator.validate(obj, errors);
```

Any ideas?

As you can see I am trying to test that if no price increase has been set, that
an error is returned when calling validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the fields `PriceIncreaseValidator,PriceIncrease,Errors` are instantiated.

Create an instance of these fields or autowire them with Spring.

To create the `Errors` object use:

`Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(priceIncrease, "priceIncrease");`

**Full Example**

```
public void testEmptyPriceIncrease() {
    PriceIncreaseValidator priceIncreaseValidator = new PriceIncreaseValidator();
    PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(priceIncrease, "priceIncrease");

    priceIncreaseValidator.validate(priceIncrease, errors); // This is where I get NPE

    assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have created an instance of PriceIncreaseValidator and PriceIncrease. However, I can't create an instance of Errors as it is an interface. Any ideas how to resolve this. Thanks.  private PriceIncreaseValidator priceIncreaseValidator = new PriceIncreaseValidator();
private PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
private Errors errors;